# Go with VSC: package command-line-arguments is not a main package

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have installed go on my machine which creates a folder \go in my home directory, which contain two folders bin and pkg, and I also have a env variable pointing to this folder:

```
GOPATH=....\go
```

I clone a GO git repo.

I now create a folder 'mygolearning' at repo root, and put a go file mytest.go inside it.

```
package mygolearning

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}
```

When I try to run it while in the folder on VSC terminal...

```
go run mytest.go
```

....I get message:

```
package command-line-arguments is not a main package
```

I see a folder 'pkg' at project root. Do I need to register my folder and file there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang: functions unused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75910554/golang-functions-unused)

Comment: I tried what is asks to do, but still same issue. Then I created a whole new workspace and put my changes there, and it worked fine. Seems project configurations are the issue.

Comment: Stop fiddling with GOPATH and never use filename arguments to go run. Read How to Write Go code and stick to it. The error is self-explaining: Executables _must_ be `package main`.

Comment: @Volker Did I mention anywhere that I change GOPATH?

Comment: @Mandroid: Yes. Let me quote you "and I also have a env variable pointing to this folder: GOPATH=....\go".

Comment: @Volker This was itself created during Go installation, not by me manually.

Comment: A Go installation doesn't set GOAPTH.

Comment: Maybe, but I myself didnt do anything extra. Infact, I was not even aware of GOPATH.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it may be that you are trying to use a .go file as the runner.

Right now the package of this golang file is "mygolearning".

But the one you call in your console / VSC terminal needs to be in package main.

So:

1. Either change the package to "main".

or

2. Add another golang file with a package of "main" and go from there.

Example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

. In a Go program, the package that contains the main function is considered the "main" package, and it is the entry point of the program when it is executed.
so the entry point is the "main" and you are trying "mygolearing"